# Post Byte Array to Server : C# (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, xamarin.android, xamarin, arrays

I am trying to post byte array to server.

My code:

```
        private void PostVideo()
        {
            byte[] data = null;
            InputStream st;
            st = new FileInputStream (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/newtest.mp4");
            data = readBytes (st);

            var _video = new VideoViewModel{Title = "title", User_Id = 1 , video = data};               

            var requestpost = HttpWebRequest.Create (string.Format (@"http://***/api/Video", ""));
            requestpost.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
            requestpost.Method = "POST";


            using (var writer = new StreamWriter (requestpost.GetRequestStream ())) {
                writer.Write (_video);
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = requestpost.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse) {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    System.Console.Out.WriteLine ("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                else
                    // response
            }
        }


        public class VideoViewModel
        {
            public int User_Id { get; set; }

            public string Title { get; set; }

            public byte[] video { get; set; }
        }


        public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream){

            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.Read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return byteBuffer.ToByteArray();
        }
```

I am not getting any error or output. break-point hit on HttpWebResponse and then nothing happens.

What am i doing wrong here?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: What size of array? On GetResponse it's sending the data to the server and wait for response, so sending the big array of data may take some time, after that break point will hit on the next row

Comment: @choper It is a video and it is around 1 mb. How long will it take?

Comment: Can not say you accuracy, depends on you network speed, but can you try to wait a little more till the breakpoint hit on the next line? I think it should hit after some time

Comment: @choper ok, thanks. will do that.